# React Hooks: How to get updated value of a state in useEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Need to update the boolean state value on map click. And based on that updated value, new component rendered.

```
const [layerClick, setLayerClick] = useState(false);
useEffect(() => {
    if (streetsCurrentHeatStateMap !== null) {
        streetsCurrentHeatStateMap.on('click', (e) => {
            if (layerClick === false) {
                popupToggler();
            }
        })
    }
}, [
    layerClick,
]);
```

And here is the popupToggler function

```
  const popupToggler = async () => {
    setLayerClick((layerClick) => !layerClick);
  }
```

And it is used for the conditional rendering of the Popup Component.

```
{layerClick && (
    <PopupContent />
)}
```

So problem is: It always call the popuptoggler function, mean the value of state not updated. Any help?

Comment: please copy the code example as text with code formatting in your question instead of linking to an image

Comment: I think this: `if (streetsCurrentHeatStateMap === null) { ... }` is wrong. You cannot access property `.on` of `null`. I assume you wanted to use `streetsCurrentHeatStateMap !== null`

Comment: What is the value of streetsCurrentHeatStateMap ?

Comment: It's a state used to store the leaflet geojson object.

Comment: So it isn't an HTMLElement, right ? Where do you render the elements ? Could you add that part of the code ?

Comment: Yes, streetsCurrentHeatStateMap is not an HTMLElement, but the above-added part "PopupContent" take values from it.